# If function in drop down list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an expert system to detect network problems. The user will have 4 question each with 3 to 4 answers. After the input from the user, the user will click the button and it will detect and solve the problem. I kinda got the idea, but i know few things are missing. At the moment, I only added some 2 random questions and answers, to check if is actually working. Please help with java script, so it will give details on the network problem depending on the answers. Thanks in advance! :)

```
  1.Can you access to the internet? <BR>

<select id="internet">

  <option value="yes">yes</option>

  <option value="No">no</option>

  <option value="Yes, but at slow">Yes, but at slow</option>

  <option value="Yes/No, it workes but it suddenly it stops and start working again ">Yes/No, it workes but it suddenly it stops and start working again</option>

</select>

<br>

<br><p>


2.Is it just your computer?<BR> 



 <select id="computer">

  <option value="yes">yes</option>

  <option value="whole company">whole company</option>

  <option value="just my department">just my department</option>

  <option value="me and few staff">me and few staff</option>

</select>

<br>

<br><p>




<button onclick="myFunction()">Detect</button>

<p id="Solution"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{

if (internet=="no"||computer=="yes")
  {
  x="check your cable is not cut or loose";
  }
else if (internet=="no"||computer=="yes")
  {
  x="connection problem";
  }
else
  {
  x="other problems....";
  }
document.getElementById("Solution").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: So... What is your question?

Comment: Is not working, and  i am new with java script. If i select any answers it just gives the same output.

Comment: so if there is no internet connection and only their computer is affected, it should say check your cable...etc.

Comment: One problem that immediately jumps out to me is that your first two `if` statements are exactly the same. So if the first one is false, the second one will also be false, and it will go to the `else` at the end.

Comment: Opps, sorry i changed it in my computer but didn't change it here. Still same output, I am sure i am missing something...maybe the dropdownlist or something in the script.

Comment: More specify your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction()
{
    var internetElem =  document.getElementById("internet");
    var internet = internetElem.options[internetElem.selectedIndex].value;
    var computerElem =  document.getElementById("computer");
    var computer= internetElem.options[internetElem.selectedIndex].value;

   if (internet=="no"||computer=="yes") {
      x="check your cable is not cut or loose";
   } else if (internet=="no"||computer=="yes") {
      x="connection problem";
   } else {
      x="other problems....";
   }
   document.getElementById("Solution").innerHTML=x;
}
```

You need something like above. Just find an element by its id, take index of selected element and get a value of selected option. Note that value will return what you have placed in `<option value="..."` and string comparison is case sensitive, so `internet == "no"`, will not work and you should change it to `internet == "No"` (or change a value in HTML markup)

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I want! Thanks for the comments! :)